# How to set bashrc shell environment

Tags: bash, bashrc

I would like to add _ENV to my bash so once I ssh to the server it shows something like this:

```
[live][root@server ~]#
```

or

```
[dev][root@server ~]#
```

How can I do this? I have been looking everywhere for this but without any luck.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stick something like this at the end of your `~/.bashrc`

```
export PS1='[live][\u@\h \w]# '
```

The dev/live is hard-coded in so you'll need to edit that unless you've got a method of picking that out.

You can also add a splash of colour to make it easier to notice.

```
export PS1='[\[\033[0;35m\]live\[\033[00m\]][\u@\h \w]# '
```